# The unique representation of parallel curve?

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $ D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2 $ be a bounded domain of class $ C^2 $, the boundary  $ \partial D $ be connected, $ v $ the unit normal of $ \partial D $ directed into the exterior domian $ \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \bar D $. We define parallel curve 
\begin{equation*}
\partial D_h := \{ z = x + h v(x) : x \in \partial D \},
\end{equation*}
with a real parameter $ h $.

**Question:** For a sufficiently small neighborhood $ U $ of $ \partial D $, why each point $ z \in U $ can be ***uniquely*** represented in the form $ z = x + h v(x) $, where $ x \in \partial D$ and $ h \in \mathbb{R} $?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Geometrically, if $h$ is smaller than the radius of curvature, the normals of length $h$ do not intersect.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I can comprehend your idea, but if there exist some strict explanation?

Comment: It's a compactness argument. Can you show that for each $x\in\partial D$ there is a neighborhood in $\partial D$ so that the mapping $g(x,t) = x+tv(x)$ is a diffeomorphism for $\epsilon$ sufficiently small?

Comment: @TedShifrin I am afraid not. I major in numerical mathematics and lack techniques in differential geometry. This is a problem which occurs in the process of examining the proof of uniqueness of Boundary integral equation. Could you help give a proof comprehensive to beginners?

Comment: Hmmm, you're going to need to know the Inverse Function Theorem.

Comment: @TedShifrin Any furthur results can be understood with appropriate reference. I am a senior Phd student with publications. The inverse function theorem can be found in the first volume of some textbook of mathematical analysis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Since you referred to the outward-pointing unit normal of $\partial D$, I'm going to assume that the curve is reasonably smooth (say $C^2$). Let's start at a point of $C=\partial D$ and parametrize $C$ by arclength $s$ with the function $x(s)$. I will denote the unit tangent and principal normal by $T$ and $N$, as is customary, with $T,N$ a right-handed system.

The Frenet equations tell us that $T'(s)=\kappa(s)N(s)$ and $N'(s)=-\kappa(s)T(s)$.  Here we're considering $\kappa$ to be the signed curvature (positive where $D$ is locally convex, negative where $D$ is locally concave). We have $v(s)=-N(s)$ globally if $C$ is oriented counterclockwise, and $v(s)=N(s)$ if $C$ is oriented clockwise. I will assume it's got the usual counterclockwise orientation. Thus, $v'(s)=\kappa(s)T(s)$.

The mapping you're considering is
$$g(s,t) = x(s)+tv(s),$$
and we have 
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial s} &= T(s)+tv'(s) = T(s)+t\kappa(s)T(s) = (1+t\kappa(s))T(s) \\
\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial t} &= v(s).
\end{align*}
Note that if $D$ is convex, $\partial g/\partial s$ is everywhere nonzero (geometrically, the focusing of the normal rays occurs going inward, not outward).

As long as $t\kappa>-1$, the partial derivatives of $g$ will be linearly independent and so, by the Inverse Function Theorem, $g$ gives a local diffeomorphism from $C\times (-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ to a neighborhood of $C$ in $\Bbb R^2$. That is, for each $p=x(s_0)\in C$, there is a neighborhood $U$ of $s_0$ and $0<\epsilon<\epsilon_0=\inf\limits_{s\in U}\{|1/\kappa(s)|\}$ on which $g$ is a diffeomorphism to its image.

By compactness, we can cover $C$ (or the appropriate closed $s$ interval) by finitely many such open sets and take the minimum $\bar\epsilon_0$ of the finite number of $\epsilon_0$ values. So the map $g\colon C\times (-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ will be a local diffeomorphism to a neighborhood of $C$ for any $\epsilon<\bar\epsilon_0$.

But is it a one-to-one mapping? Locally, surely, but why globally? (If the region gets thin so that points relatively far away along $C$ are close in the plane, that could be an issue.) So we need one last compactness argument. We proceed by contradiction. Suppose that for every $n\in\Bbb N$ we have points $s_n\ne s'_n$ so that $g(s_n,t_n) = g(s'_n,t'_n)$ for some $t_n,t'_n$ with $|t_n|,|t'_n|\le 1/n$. By compactness, we may pass to a subsequence and assume $s_n,s'_n\to s_0$. (I'll let you worry about the special case that $s_n\to 0$ and $s'_n\to L$, where $L$ is the arclength of $C$.) And of course $t_n,t'_n\to 0$. But we already know that $g$ is one-to-one on some neighborhood $U\times (-\epsilon,\epsilon)$. Since $(s_n,t_n)$ and $(s'_n,t'_n)$ lie in this neighborhood for sufficiently large $n$, our scenario cannot take place.

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer!

Comment: This is a question after three years. In the contradiction part, why can we assume that $\vert  t_n \vert $ and $\vert  t'_n \vert $ are smaller than $\frac{1}{n}$ at the same time? Besides, the compactness can guarantee that we can choose convergent subsequence, but why the same limit?

Comment: Because if no $\epsilon>0$ works, then for each $n$ the map fails to be one-to-one on $|t|<1/n$. For your second question, pass to a subsequence of a subsequence.

Comment: As to the second, how to choose  the subsubsequence with the same limit?

Comment: Think about it. Can they have different limits (not counting $0$ and $L$)?

Comment: I missed it....